# Updation Error on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: repository, release-management

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal 
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2):

The Wine PPA is obsolete. It does not provide packages for your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version.

Please remove the PPA by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

To fix signature of the LibreOffice PPA re-add it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 83FBA1751378B444
```

and then run `sudo apt-get update` .

Comment: problem not resolved